# Is there DOM Element for this or something like that?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner and I have some issue with my HTML & JavaScript code.
Mainly I want to send a notifications like "Logged in!" & "Fill in the remaining data".

Here's the HTML code:

```
<input type="email" id="emailToLogin" placeholder="Enter your email" />
<input type="password" id="passwordToLogin" placeholder="Enter your password"/>

 <button type="submit" id="log" onclick="notification(emailInput, passwordInput)">
 <p>
    Log in
 </p>
</button>
<h1 id="successful"></h1>
<h1 id="unsuccessful"></h1>
```

JavaScript code:

```
let emailInput = document.getElementById("emailToLogin");
let passwordInput = document.getElementById("passwordToLogin");

function notification(emailInput, passwordInput) {
    if (emailInput ==  "" || passwordInput == "") {
        document.getElementById("unsuccessful").innerHTML = "Please enter the remaining data!";
    }

}
```

To be more specific, I want to do this in JavaScript, no matter what. I have a code for redirection to the main site of this little project, but I think it's not important.

I already tried to change "" to undefined or null, and it didn't work.

Comment: `emailInput.value` is your friend!

Comment: You haven't explained what this would do if it "worked".

Comment: @ScottHunter It must show text like this: "Logged in" or, if it's not filled, "Fill in the remaining data!"

Comment: @moonwave99 what if it didn't work?

Comment: Typo?  You're trying to compare the elements themselves, rather than [their values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77482240/is-there-dom-element-for-this-or-something-like-that#comment136597253_77482240).  (Additionally, I suspect you're very close to confusing yourself with different variables of the same name.  You may want to remove the function arguments entirely and just use the global variables.)

Comment: @David 
So .  value   will not be solution or what? It doesn't work for me and I can't understand it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't doing what you think it is:

```
if (emailInput ==  "" || passwordInput == "") {
```

If you were to `console.log(emailInput)` (and/or `passwordInput`) you'll see that these are not string values, they are entire DOM elements.  Which you queried from the DOM here:

```
let emailInput = document.getElementById("emailToLogin");
let passwordInput = document.getElementById("passwordToLogin");
```

To compare their *values*, you need to read the values from the elements:

```
if (emailInput.value ==  "" || passwordInput.value == "") {
```

---

Additionally, I suspect you're very close to confusing yourself with multiple variables of the same name.  You define these globally:

```
let emailInput = document.getElementById("emailToLogin");
let passwordInput = document.getElementById("passwordToLogin");
```

And then shadow them with local variables here:

```
function notification(emailInput, passwordInput) {
```

This coincidentally works because you happen to be passing those global variables to the function:

```
onclick="notification(emailInput, passwordInput)"
```

But this is a bug waiting to happen.  Keep the intent clear.  You could use a different name for the local variables, and expect the values instead of the entire elements:

```
function notification(email, password) {
  if (email ==  "" || password == "") {
    document.getElementById("unsuccessful").innerHTML = "Please enter the remaining data!";
  }
}
```

Then pass those values:

```
onclick="notification(emailInput.value, passwordInput.value)"
```

Or perhaps just rely on the global variables and not use function arguments at all:

```
function notification() {
  if (emailInput.value ==  "" || passwordInput.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("unsuccessful").innerHTML = "Please enter the remaining data!";
  }
}
```

And of course remove the arguments from the function call:

```
onclick="notification()"
```

It's really up to you which approach you'd prefer.